# Submit Contact Form w/o Reloading Page Using Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, bootstrap-4, form-submit

I am following a guide to build a bootstrap contact form and submit it through mail.php without having to reload the page using ajax. I am able to get the form to work up until I try implementing ajax. I get stuck because the instructions arent clear as to which code exactly needs to be replaced and where the new code is supposed to go. Here is a link to the guide I am following and the section I am stuck at:

[Sending email without reloading page using AJAX](https://mdbootstrap.com/components/bootstrap-contact-form/#ajax)

This is the site I am trying to get it to work on: [CRANE TECH. NET](https://crane-tech.net)

I am not so familiar with php so I'm thinking that is where I am messing it up at.

Here is the exact code I am using:

**HTML**

```
<section class="section">
                        <h2 class="section-heading  text-muted h4 pt-4">Free Consultation</h2>
                        <!--CONTACT DESCRIPTION-->
                        <p class="section-description">Are you ready to turn your vision into a reality? Fill out the contact form below and a member of our team will get back to you as soon as possible. Let's bring your idea to life!</p>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <form id="contact-form" name="contact-form" action="mail.php" method="POST">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <!--NAME INPUT-->
                                        <div class="col-12">
                                            <div class="md-form">
                                                <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="* NAME" required>
                                                <label for="name" class=""></label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <!--EMAIL INPUT-->
                                        <div class="col-12">
                                            <div class="md-form">
                                                <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="* EMAIL" required>
                                                <label for="email" class=""></label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">

                                        <!-- PHONE NUMBER INPUT -->
                                        <div class="col-12">
                                            <div class="md-form">
                                                <input type="text" id="clientPhone" name="clientPhone" class="form-control" placeholder="PHONE" required>
                                                <label for="phone number" class=""></label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <!--SUBJECT INPUT-->
                                        <div class="col-12">
                                            <div class="md-form">
                                                <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" class="form-control" placeholder="* SUBJECT" required>
                                                <label for="subject" class=""></label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">

                                        <!--MESSAGE INPUT-->
                                        <div class="col-12">
                                            <div class="md-form">
                                                <textarea type="text" id="message" name="message" rows="3" class="form-control md-textarea" placeholder="* MESSAGE" required></textarea>
                                                <label for="message"></label>
                                            </div>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                                <!-- SUBMIT BUTTON -->
                                <div class=" col-3 offset-3 offset-md-4 mb-4">
                                    <button class="btn btn-warning" onclick="validateForm()">Send <i class="fa fa-paper-plane ml-1"></i></button>
                                </div>
                                <div id="status" class="text-muted col-12 col-md-8 offset-md-2 my-1"></div>
                            </div>
```

**JS**

```
function validateForm() {
var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
if (name == "") {
    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "Name cannot be empty";
    return false;
}
var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
if (email == "") {
    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "Email cannot be empty";
    return false;
} else {
    var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    if (!re.test(email)) {
        document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "Email format invalid";
        return false;
    }
}

var subject = document.getElementById('subject').value;
if (subject == "") {
    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "Subject cannot be empty";
    return false;
}
var message = document.getElementById('message').value;
if (message == "") {
    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "Message cannot be empty";
    return false;
}
document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "Sending...";
formData = {
    'name': $('input[name=name]').val(),
    'email': $('input[name=email]').val(),
    'clientPhone': $('input[name=clientPhone]').val(),
    'subject': $('input[name=subject]').val(),
    'message': $('textarea[name=message]').val()

};
document.getElementById('contact-form').submit();

$.ajax({
    url: "mail.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: formData,
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

        $('#status').text(data.message);
        if (data.code) //If mail was sent successfully, reset the form.
            $('#contact-form').closest('form').find("input[type=text], textarea").val("");
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        $('#status').text(jqXHR);
    }
});
}
```

**MAIL.PHP**

```
<?php
if(isset( $_POST['name']))
  $name = $_POST['name'];
if(isset( $_POST['email']))
  $email = $_POST['email'];
if(isset( $_POST['clientPhone']))
  $clientPhone = $_POST['clientPhone'];
if(isset( $_POST['subject']))
  $subject = $_POST['subject'];
if(isset( $_POST['message']))
  $message = $_POST['message'];

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$clientPhone = $_POST['clientPhone']
$message = $_POST['message'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
header('Content-Type: application/json');
if ($name === ''){
  print json_encode(array('message' => 'Name cannot be empty', 'code' => 0));
  exit();
}
if ($email === ''){
  print json_encode(array('message' => 'Email cannot be empty', 'code' => 0));
  exit();
} else {
  if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
  print json_encode(array('message' => 'Email format invalid.', 'code' => 0));
  exit();
  }
}
if ($subject === ''){
  print json_encode(array('message' => 'Subject cannot be empty', 'code' => 0));
  exit();
}
if ($message === ''){
  print json_encode(array('message' => 'Message cannot be empty', 'code' => 0));
  exit();
}

//   if ($name === ''){
//     echo "Name cannot be empty.";
//     echo "<br>";
//     echo "<br>";
//     echo "<a href='index.html'>GO BACK</a>";
//     die();
//   }
//   if ($email === ''){
//     echo "Email cannot be empty.";
//     echo "<br>";
//     echo "<br>";
//     echo "<a href='index.html'>GO BACK</a>";
//     die();
//   } else {
//     if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
//       echo "Email format invalid.";
//       echo "<br>";
//       echo "<br>";
//       echo "<a href='index.html'>GO BACK</a>";
//       die();
//     }
//   }
//   if ($subject === ''){
//     echo "Subject cannot be empty.";
//     echo "<br>";
//     echo "<br>";
//     echo "<a href='index.html'>GO BACK</a>";
//     die();
//   }
//   if ($message === ''){
//     echo "Message cannot be empty.";
//     echo "<br>";
//     echo "<br>";
//     echo "<a href='index.html'>GO BACK</a>";
//     die();
//   }

$content="From: $name \n Email: $email \n Phone #: $clientPhone \n Subject: $subject \n Message: $message";
$recipient = "support@crane-tech.net";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $content, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
print json_encode(array('message' => 'Email successfully sent!', 'code' => 1));
exit();
?>
```

Comment: You don't appear to have a form, so you have no data to send in your `formData`. For instance, you have no `<input name="name">`, so you have no element to target with `input[name=name]`. Please post your actual form if you have one. Also, what **specifically** is not working the way you are expecting it to work? And do you get any error messages?

Comment: I'm a bit stumbled about the lack of basic knowledge combined with a website that offers knowledge...

Comment: @Jeff It's just a project I am working on over time. I dont intend to market myself or present the website until I am confident in my knowledge & abilities. Thanks for pointing out that I am still a n00b though. aha.

Comment: @ObsidianAge I updated the html to include the form as well. The problem I am having is the form wont send to the designated email. I get an HTTP ERROR 500 when I click the submit button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Main Issue

You main issue is that there is a missing semcolon (;) and the end of line 15 in the php code.

#### Other Issues

Your website is using JQuery Slim, `$.ajax` is not included in the slim version so you are getting an error due to that. To fix this just include the full JQuery or do the ajax without JQuery.

You may also want to get rid of this line:
`document.getElementById('contact-form').submit();`
because it is causing a redirect when you are already manually submitting your data.

You should remove these lines because you have already set them:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$clientPhone = $_POST['clientPhone']
$message = $_POST['message'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
```

---

#### Unrelated note:

If you are already using JQuery, you should be using it - instead of doing this:
`document.getElementById('status')`
You should be using:
`$('#status')`

Comment: I removed that line and added a <script> tag linking to the full minified version of jquery now, but am still getting that same http 500 error and now the status Id returns "[Object object]" instead of "Sending..." when I click the submit button. 

Thank you for your quick answer and trying to help me.

Comment: The 500 error is an external server error check the logs to see what the problems is.
You can also add the following lines at the top of your php page to show errors:
`ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: The error log shows "PHP Warning:  Cannot assign an empty string to a string offset in /home... on line 426". It is no longer giving me the 500 error, but only returns "[object Object]" in the status field. If you go to crane-tech.net and try to submit the contact form from the modal you can see exactly what Im talking about.

Comment: Your website still appears to be including the JQuery slim - change that. The page is redirecting me - have you still got that line - `document.getElementById('contact-form').submit();`? The errors will output onto the mail page - but are not because of an error check the logs and see if they show something.

Comment: Found what was causing the error - updated the answer.

Comment: omfgoodess man. Thank you so much for informing me about the "error log". The error was this: "PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$subject' (T_VARIABLE) in /home.../mail.php on line 18" It turns out I was missing a ':' ahahaha. Its always something so stupid. Thank you for your time & help.